# Export page as subdirectory (subdir/index.html) in NextJS

Tags: next.js

I have a page in my NextJS app: about.tsx. On doing a `next export`, it creates an about.html in the output directory. However, I want a subdirectory "about" with an index.html (about/index.html) as the output.

I tried creating a directory in pages - "about" and putting the about.tsx as index.tsx within it. But, it still continues to create an about.html instead of about/index.html. Is there any way I can force NextJS to create about/index.html instead of about.html.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by providing trailingSlash config in next.config.js.

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
  ...
}
```